# winapi CComboBox draw on edit item

Tags: winapi, mfc, combobox, ccombobox

i am writing in WinApi/MFC  my own control CCustomComboBox , which inherits from CComboBox, and i would like to draw in items instead of putting into them only a text.

I achieved this by defining a style CBS_OWNDERDRAWVARIABLE and then draw in OnDrawItem function, but i don't know how to draw on a main window of ComboBox( select item).(the window on the top of combo box)
I can call on it for example SetWindowText() but I would like to draw anything on it for example LineTo().
In general i would like to copy what is drawn on a particular item of combo box to edit/main item.
But to do this first i would like to know how to draw on it.
Thanks for advices!
Przemek

Comment: This article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174667 shows how to subclass editbox part of a combobox. I am not sure that after subclassing you can draw in an edit box, but try this.

Comment: hmm I still don't know how to solve it